# If $x+y+xy=3$ , $y+z+yz=8$ and $z+x+xz=15$ then Find $6xyz$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x+y+xy=3$ , $y+z+yz=8$ and $z+x+xz=15$ then

Find $6xyz$.

How can I approach this problem?

I need some hints. Thanks.

Comment: Try subtracting $(z+1)$ times the first equation from $(y+1)$ times the last equation. This should get you a way to express $y$ in terms of $z$. Then you should be able to solve for the rest of the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x + y + xy = 3  \implies    ( 1 + x ) ( 1 + y ) = 4\tag1$

$y + z + yz = 8  \implies   ( 1 + y ) ( 1 + z ) = 9\tag2$

$z + x + zx = 15  \implies   ( 1 + z ) ( 1 + x ) = 16\tag3$

Multiplying $(1)$ and $(3)$, we have

$$( 1 + x )^2 ( 1 + y )( 1 + z )=4\cdot 16\implies ( 1 + x )^2= \dfrac{64}{9}\qquad \text{{using $(2)$}}.$$ 
$$\implies x=\pm \dfrac{8}{3}-1=\dfrac{5}{3}~, -\dfrac{11}{3}$$
From $(1)$, $~y=-1+\dfrac{4}{1+x}=\dfrac{1}{2},~-\dfrac{5}{2}~$ respectively for $~x=\dfrac{5}{3}~, -\dfrac{11}{3}~$

From $(3)$, $~z=-1+\dfrac{16}{1+x}=5,~-7~$ respectively for $~x=\dfrac{5}{3}~, -\dfrac{11}{3}~$

So **case I:**  When $~x=\dfrac{5}{3},~y=\dfrac{1}{2},~z=5~,$
$$~6xyz=6\times \dfrac{5}{3} \times\dfrac{1}{2}\times 5=25~.$$

and **case II:** When $~x=-\dfrac{11}{3},~y=-\dfrac{5}{2},~z=-7~,$
$$~6xyz=6\times (-)\dfrac{11}{3} \times(-)\dfrac{5}{2}\times(-) 7=-385~.$$

Answer (score 3):

For convenience, we just need to look at one equation, $$x+y+xy=3  \implies (x+1)(y+1)=4$$

hence we define

> $a=x+1,b=y+1,c=z+1$

and we obtain

> $ab=4,bc=9,ac=16$

You solve easily by that hint then.

Comment: It should be $x+y+xy=3 \implies (x+1)(y+1) = 4$.

Comment: OK, thanks for hiding the content above.